# how can i change the color of rows using jquery? based on conditions

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

```
 <tr class="acti">//class 
<script type="text/javascript">
  var status =  $(this).parent().parent().children(".activity-status").attr("data-value");//Jquery value according to which the colour of the upper class is going to be changed
```

Iam using a for each loop show the results so the status value varies and i want to change the colour according to the value for e.g if status == 1 then the colour of the class is red and when it is 2 colour changes to green

Comment: Can you please paste a jsfiddle of this with the html table structure?

Comment: what object store in $(this) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
var status =  $(this).parent().parent().children(".activity-status").attr("data-value");

if(status == 1){
    $("tr").css("color","yourcolor");
}
else if(status == 2){
    $("tr").css("color","anothercolor");
}
```

Comment: i have already done it but it is taking the first value of the records list

Comment: you mean just the first row?

Comment: just the first one

Comment: then write : `$("tr:first").css("color","yourcolor");` or `$("table tr:first").css("color","yourcolor");`